# Spring Integration Kafka : Inbound channel adapter vs message driven adapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am new to using spring integration kafka. I was reading the docs, and got confused between Inbound channel adapter and message driven channel adapters. Can some one explain the difference between them . Also does spring integration for kafka has some error handling mechanism like the one present in spring integration for amqp/rmq( using dlq).

PS : We are trying to move away from rabbit mq to kafka as source of messages in ithe spring integration framework

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message-driven adapter is similar to the rabbitmq inbound adapter in that messages are "pushed" into your integration flow whenever records are available in the topic.

The inbound channel adapter uses the "pull" model, where you poll for messages on a schedule. There is an equivalent for RabbitMQ (since 5.0.1) but it's not currently configurable with XML.

> some error handling mechanism

The SIK components are subclasses of the same classes as all other SI components, so the same facilities are generally available, yes.

Comment: Thanks Gary, can you point to me specific example where dead letter topics are used for error handling and they give the messages back to normal topics after certain delays .

Comment: I presume you are referring to RabbitMQ's ability to configure a TTL on the DLQ such that expired DLQ messages get routed back to the original queue. That is a RabbitMQ feature, not Spring Integration. Kafka has nothing equivalent to that; you have to write your own code to read from the dead letter topic and publish back to the original topic.